# .gnupg/ and gpg.conf owner and permissions to satisty both GnuPG and Enigmail

Tags: permissions, gnupg, ownership, enigmail

Enigmail wants `$USER` to have the write permission on `~/.gnupg/` directory but the `gpg` tool then complains about insecure permissions :

```bash
$ ls -ld ~/.gnupg
drwxrwx--- 1 root xyzt 248 févr. 25 16:34 /home/xyzt/.gnupg/
$ sudo gpg --list-keys >/dev/null 
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/xyzt/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
```

and if I switch the group and user owners, I get another warning :

```bash
$ sudo chown -R $USER:root ~/.gnupg
$ ls -ld ~/.gnupg
drwxrwx--- 1 xyzt root 248 févr. 25 16:38 /home/xyzt/.gnupg/
$ sudo gpg --list-keys >/dev/null 
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/xyzt/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
```

What are the owner and permissions on `~/.gnupg/` and `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` to satisty both GnuPG and Enigmail ?

Comment: It's complaining about the read/write privileges.  Root should not be ownign that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is the ownership and permissions on both folders *and* files in there.  The home directory `~/.gnupg` directory should only be owned by that user, and NOT by any other user; the same applies for the directory's permissions and the file permissions inside it.  (`root` would still be able to read to, write to, and traverse through it anyways, you don't need `root` to be group or owner for any reason)

Set the owner for the configuration file to your user and group:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg
```

Then make sure it's only readable by your own user - no other users OR groups should be in the permissions schema:

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.gnupg
```

Specifically for that last error about `gpg.conf` having insecure permissions, also make sure that `gpg.conf` is in read/write for user, read-only for group, and read-only for 'other':

```
sudo chmod 644 ~/.gnupg
```

This should resolve the errors you're seeing.  (You can use `sudo` for these commands, but DO NOT use `sudo` when working with your own GPG keyrings or using the `gpg` command unless you need `root`'s keyring - you'll have incorrect permissions otherwise).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. BTW, I was using `sudo gpg` because I thought the Launchpad PPA repos. keys where stored in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`

Comment: @SebMa Those're only manged by `apt-key` - you need `sudo` for that but NOT for other `gpg` commands such as key retrieval and such from key servers, or for messing with your local `gpg.conf` or such

Comment: Can you please have a look at my other question regarding apt/gpg, because it seems I have messed things up a bit on my other PC : https://askubuntu.com/q/1120843/426176 ?

Comment: @SebMa That issue I can't assist with; it's a different issue unrelated to filesystem permissions like this one is.